# Love2d:STI and bumb.lua plugin

Tags: lua, love2d

this is my code to initialize bump world by using STI map

```
function love.load()
require 'conf';
require 'vars';
bump = require 'maps/bump';
loc= require("maps/lv1")
local sti = require "maps"
world = bump.newWorld(16)
test = love.audio.newSource("audio/03 Towering Chieftain.mp3","static")
map = sti(loc ,{"bump"})
map:bump_init(world)
end
```

and this is the error that came to me

```
    Error

main.lua:11: attempt to call method 'bump_init' (a nil value)


Traceback

main.lua:11: in function 'load'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
[C]: in function 'xpcall'
```

Comment: Can you move all your require statements out of your love.load()? And also post your maps file? If you actually just upload you whole game to a Github that would be a lot easier to debug

Comment: my file isn't sti plugin when i got the plugin  bump.newWorld didn't worked any of bump function didn't work so i try to make the bump.lua the libarry i required them the both but the libarary don't work the collsions of map and getting the require out of load () don't affect

Comment: Could you rephrase that last sentence?

Comment: Thanks sam i solved everything by cleaning code and renewing files